# Unknown Issue with Babel__Core and tsconfig.json

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js

### Information regarding issue:

- Vue is being used
- Babel__Core is involved (not completely sure why)
- I do not know the problem.

### Error Message:

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'babel__core'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'babel__core'
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
  {
  "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
  },
  {
  "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  {
  "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
  }
 ]
}
```

If you know any information or need to see anything else do not be afraid to let me know. I tried making this as detailed as possible.